# CloudKit publicDB development save fail

Tags: ios, swift3, cloudkit

I am saving a record to a public database in an app that is currently under external testing.

One of my testers has a problem that I can seem to work out - she saves the record, which the program thinks saves currently, and throws no errors, but the record doesn't show up on iCloud, and we cannot retrieve the record.

Other testers have not had this issue - only her.  Her iCloud and iCloud drive is turned on and enabled for the app.

The code too save the record:

```
let newRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Club")
    loadedRecord = newRecord

    publicDB.save(newRecord) { (nil, error) in
        if error != nil {
            dispError = String(describing: error)
            print("Create Club Error = \(String(describing: error))")
        } else {
            //dispError = nil
            clubCreated[0] = true
        }
    }
```

The code to retrieve the record:

```
let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "self contains '\(predSearchTerm)'")
    print(predSearchTerm)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: ClubType, predicate: namePredicate)
    publicDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { [unowned self] results, error in
        if error != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                dispError = String(describing: error)
                print("Cloud Query Error - Fetch Clubs: \(dispError)")
            }
            return
        }

        //dispError = nil

        self.items.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
        results?.forEach({ (record: CKRecord) in
            loadedRecord = results?[0]
            self.items.append(Club(record: record, database: self.publicDB))
        })
        clubLoaded = true
    }
```

When I check to see the number of items retrieved it says 0, and the record cannot be found on iCloud.

Comment: Why do you have `publicDB.save(newRecord) { (nil, error) in` instead of `publicDB.save(newRecord) { (record, error) in`?

Comment: @rmaddy - I have never used the `(record, error)` version - what is the benefit?  It still throws the errors in the version I have used

Comment: Using the proper parameters allows you to access the record that was actually saved.

Comment: @rmaddy it isn't throwing an error so the code there would never run as during the save `error = nil`